# SQL - use variable as column in SELECT statement and WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to pull the students that are tardy for the previous period from our attendance database (SQL Server 2008). The period attendance is stored in `ATT.A1, ATT.A2 ... ATT.A7`. I want to schedule a job to run each hour, starting at 9am, and pull the tardy students, but I can't figure out the code.

Here's my code (pseudo-code):

```
Declare @Period varchar(6)
Set @Period = 'att.a' + Cast((DATENAME(hour, GETDATE()) - 8) as varchar(1))

Select SC, SN, DT, @Period as Period, ATT.A1
From ATT
Where SC = '9' and @Period = 'T' 
    and DT = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

When I use this, I get no results. If I remove `@Period = 'T'` from the Where clause, I get the following:

```
9   5177    2012-08-24 00:00:00.000 att.a1  T
9   5211    2012-08-24 00:00:00.000 att.a1   
9   5225    2012-08-24 00:00:00.000 att.a1  T
9   5229    2012-08-24 00:00:00.000 att.a1  T
9   5235    2012-08-24 00:00:00.000 att.a1  V
9   5242    2012-08-24 00:00:00.000 att.a1  T
9   5268    2012-08-24 00:00:00.000 att.a1
```

I know that when I use `@Period` in the `SELECT` statement and `WHERE` clause it's using the literal string value of `@Period`, but I need it to use the value of `@Period` as `Table.Column`.

So, at 9:00 it will select from `ATT.A1`, 10:00 from `ATT.A2` ... 15:00 from `ATT.A7` and each time compare whether ATT.A# = 'T'

I hope that's clear.

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Comment: Could you provide sample input, i.e. `ATT` data, and the desired results?

Comment: @HABO  Thank you.  The Case Statement that Michael provided below works, but I changed it to apply what you talked about here, i.e. I `Set @Date = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` and then used `and DT = @Date` in the Where clause of the actual query, so that it would only `GETDATE()` once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server makes a distinction between a string containing a column name, and the column name itself, so you'll either need to use dynamic sql, or a case statement to translate the string to the actual column name as illustrated below:

**Case Statement (I'd recommend this one):**

```
Select SC, SN, DT, @Period as Period, ATT.A1
From ATT
Where 
    SC = '9' 
    and DT = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    and case @period
        when 'att.a1' then att.a1
        when 'att.a2' then att.a2
        when 'att.a3' then att.a3
        when 'att.a4' then att.a4
        when 'att.a5' then att.a5
        when 'att.a6' then att.a6
        when 'att.a7' then att.a7
    end = 'T'
```

**Dynamic Sql:**

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)
Set @sql = '
    Select SC, SN, DT, @Period as Period, ATT.A1
    From ATT
    Where SC = '9' and ' + @Period + ' = ''T'' 
        and DT = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)'
Exec(@sql)
```

Comment: The Case Statement you provided worked.  Thank you for the help.